# Using events in a shorter way

Tags: javascript, dom-events, redundancy

I have been cleaning up my js code and I was wondering if it is possible to use events in a generic way.

I have a form which responds with an `oninput` event

Now I have for each inputfield a specific instruction of what the event should do.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
    firstname.oninput = function () {
    updatePreview();
    updatePostHeader();
    showPreview();
};
lastname.oninput = function () {
    updatePreview();
    showPreview();
};
age.oninput = function () {
    updatePreview();
    showPreview();
};
job.oninput = function () {
    updatePreview();
    showPreview();
};
avatar.oninput = function () {
    updateAvatar();
    showPreview();
};
message.oninput = function () {
    updatePreview();
    showPreview();
};
```

As you can see it's a lot of redundancy.

Can I simplify this like I did below or something like that?

```
    for(var i=0; i<inputFields.length; i++) {
    inputFields[i].oninput = function() {
        updatePreview();
        showPreview();
    };
}
```

Comment: Yes you can, just make an array of your inputs.

Comment: Yep, I did, but how to invoke now?

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure how you are getting variables like: `lastname`, `age` etc. But the cleanest way would be to put them in an array like you suggested. Like:

```
var controlIds = [
    {"id": 'id1', "functions": [updatePreview, showPreview]},
    {"id": 'id2', "functions": [updatePreview, updatePostHeader, showPreview]}
];
controlIds.map(function (item){
    item["element"] = document.getElementById(item["id"]);
    return item;
}).forEach(function(elem) {
    elem["element"].oninput = function () {
        elem["functions"].forEach(function(fn) { fn(); });
    }
});
```

Comment: I get the variables by input values and using document.getElementById

Comment: But all the `oninput` handlers are not identical so this doesn't handle that.  I thought that was a key part of the problem here.  They are similar, but not identical.

Comment: @jfriend00 Implementing that shouldn't be difficult at all. Let every element of the array be a tuple: `[control, shouldUpdatePostHeaderBeCalled]`. Use the boolean second element to call the `updatePostHeader(..)` function.

Comment: @Thrustmaster - I agree, but I thought that's what the OP was asking for and you're not answering that.

Comment: @jfriend00: Updated with a more generic implementation. Hope that's what OP is looking for.

Comment: Just to be clear. Those functions are all identical, because I split up the function update into two parts, but recently I've merged this again

Answer (score 0):

If the fields belong to the same form/parent you can register the oninput event to the parent and delegate it to all its children

```
parent.on('event', childType, handler);
```

Consider the above snippet as being pseudocode as I don't know if you are using a specific library, and how event handling works. Add a bit more context and we can ellaborate further.

P.S. The problem with registering handlers via foreach is that you are actually creating functions within a loop(the handlers) and that is costly in terms of performance and error-prone in some situations.

Comment: But all the `oninput` handlers are not identical so this doesn't handle that.  I thought that was a key part of the problem here.  They are similar, but not identical.

Comment: They are now, I've edited it in the question :) I also didn't get your abstract answer, could you give a better explanation?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can move `showPreview()` function into common parent event handler due to the fact that `oninput` event will bubble up to the parent element. Then the code will simplify to:

```
firstname.oninput = function () {
    updatePreview();
    updatePostHeader();
};
lastname.oninput = updatePreview;
age.oninput = updatePreview
job.oninput = updatePreview;
avatar.oninput = updateAvatar;
message.oninput = updatePreview;

form.oninput = showPreview;
```

Check simplified demo below.

```js
lastname.oninput = updatePreview;
form.oninput = showPreview;

function updatePreview() {
    alert('update preview');
}

function showPreview() {
    alert('show preview');
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" id="lastname" />
</form>
```

Comment: The best way to describe a problem is showing all the code. But I'll give you a better explanation: I've been building a forum and for that I use a form to make posts. Every time when a user is going to add a post a preview shows up. So I created on each inputfield an event to show the preview and for every field it will update those preview

Answer (score 0):

I've the following answer to my question:

```
form.oninput = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
        inputFields[i].oninput = function () {
            updatePreview();
            showPreview();
        };
    }
};
```

It is possible to loop with events.

All you guys thanks for your replies!